# My Import/Post Button not working when clicked

Tags: php, laravel, web, button, upload

I'm confused about my web application using laravel framework version 10. Here's the code for the webview I'm building.

```
<form action="{{ url('dashboard/singkron-riwayat-pendidikan-mahasiswa') }}" 
                        method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="formImport">
                        @csrf
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-6 @error('semester') has-danger @enderror">
                                <label>Semester</label>
                                <select class="form-control @error('semester') form-control-danger @enderror"
                                    name="semester">
                                    @foreach ($semester['data'] as $semester)
                                        <option value="{{ $semester['id_semester'] }}"
                                            {{ old('semester') == $semester['id_semester'] ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                                            {{ $semester['nama_semester'] }}
                                        </option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                                @error('semester')
                                    <label class="error text-danger mt-2">{{ $message }}</label>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-6 @error('file') has-danger @enderror">
                                <label>File</label>
                                <input type="file" name="file" class="file-upload-default">
                                <div class="input-group col-xs-12">
                                    <input type="text"
                                        class="form-control file-upload-info @error('file') form-control-danger @enderror"
                                        disabled>
                                    <span class="input-group-append">
                                        <button
                                            class="file-upload-browse btn btn-light @error('file') border-danger @enderror border"
                                            type="button">Pilih File</button>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                @error('file')
                                    <label class="error text-danger mt-2">{{ $message }}</label>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-right">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnImport">Import</button>
</div></form>
```

The following is also for the controller that I use.

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'semester' => 'required',
            'file' => 'required|mimes:xls,xlsx'
        ]);

        $fileUpload = $request->file('file');
        $aktivitas = new RiwayatPendidikanMahasiswa;
        $aktivitas->import($fileUpload);

        if($aktivitas->failures()->isNotEmpty()) {
            return back()->with('import-error', $aktivitas->failures()[0]);
        } else {
            $dataAktivitas = $aktivitas->toArray($fileUpload);

            foreach ($dataAktivitas[0] as $key => $data) {
                try {
                    $recordInsertRiwayatMahasiswa = [
                        'id_mahasiswa' => $data['id_mahasiswa'],
                        'nim' => $data['nim'],
                        'id_jenis_daftar' => $data['id_jenis_daftar'],
                        'id_jalur_daftar' => $data['id_jalur_daftar'],
                        'id_periode_masuk' => $request->semester,
                        'tanggal_daftar' => $data['tanggal_daftar'],
                        'id_perguruan_tinggi' => $data['id_perguruan_tinggi'],
                        'id_prodi' => $data['id_prodi'],
                        'id_bidang_minat' => $data['id_bidang_minat'],
                        'sks_diakui' => $data['sks_diakui'],
                        'id_pembiayaan' => $data['id_pembiayaan'],
                        'biaya_masuk' => $data['biaya_masuk'],
                    ];

                    $insertRiwayatPendidikanMahasiswa = new NeoFeeder([
                        'act' => 'InsertAktivitasMahasiswa',
                        'record' => $recordInsertRiwayatMahasiswa
                    ]);

                    $responseInsertRiwayatMahasiswa = $insertRiwayatPendidikanMahasiswa->getData();

                    if ($responseInsertRiwayatMahasiswa['error_code'] == '0') {
                        ImportLog::create([
                            'act' => 'InsertAktivitasMahasiswa',
                            'status' => 'Sukses',
                            'description' => 'Aktivitas Mahasiswa ' . $data['judul'] . ' sukses diimport'
                        ]);
                    } else {
                        ImportLog::create([
                            'act' => 'InsertAktivitasMahasiswa',
                            'status' => 'Gagal',
                            'description' => 'Aktivitas Mahasiswa ' . $data['judul'] . ' gagal diimport. ' . $responseInsertRiwayatMahasiswa['error_desc']
                        ]);
                    }

                } catch (\Throwable $th) {
                    //throw $th;
                }
            }

            return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Sukses import file. Riwayat import dapat dilihat pada menu Log Import');
        }
    }
```

this is for routes code :

```
Route::get('singkron-riwayat-pendidikan-mahasiswa', [SingkronRiwayatPendidikanMahasiswaController::class, 'index']);
            Route::post('singkron-riwayat-pendidikan-mahasiswa', [SingkronRiwayatPendidikanMahasiswaController::class, 'store']);
```

i feel confused about this problem, because for other page, file upload button can run with the same code structure

I'm building a web application. And having problems when I want to upload a file into the application. The upload button on my app doesn't work.

Comment: Are you getting any error when clicked on Import button?